# Tensor products over Ring of Integers

Tags: extension-field, tensor-products

I am having trouble computing the following tensor product(s): $$\mathcal {O}_{Q}  \otimes _\mathbb {Z} \mathbb {C} = $$ Where in this case we use the ring of integers of the field of rationals, or how it generalizes  where $\mathcal {O}_{K}$ is the ring of integers of a finite extension $\mathbb {Q}$≤K.

Comment: "the ring of integers of the field of rationals" isn't that just $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Do you want this tensor product as a ring or as a module?  It is more complicated to describe its structure as a ring.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathcal{O} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathcal{O} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C})
\cong (\mathcal{O} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C}$$

$$\mathcal{O}_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q} \cong K$$

$$ (\mathbb{Q}[x] / f(x)) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C}
\cong \mathbb{C}[x] / f(x) $$